# Doesn't search any discoverable devices

Tags: android

Can any one describe what is wrong with this code. It didn't search devices, and it showed some paired devices.

Project hosted [here](https://github.com/luugiathuy/Remote-Bluetooth-Android/tree/master/RemoteBluetooth) in Github.

Comment: The code looks OK. I am using something very similar. are you sure you have your BT activated when scanning?

Comment: this looks heavily based on the bluetooth chat application. When you compile and run the bluetooth chat application, does it work any differently?

Comment: @user387184: operation of BTchat (and this app) for onStart() for the main activity screen is to activate BT if it's not already activated.

Comment: @JulianHigginson: So, What should I do now??

Comment: @YasirAdnan: import the bluetooth chat application from scratch. compile and run on your android device. does it behave differently to your modified version of it? If so - you will need to look at the differences between the original and yours. I notice you have renamed things to suit your new purpose for the program. Check after all the renaming that everything points to all the right things still.

Comment: @JulianHigginson: Thanks!!Now, It search new devices.I replaced the code with BTChat sample code.I'm facing another problem now "Unable to connect". Someone said to use "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" as UUID.I just want to know,is there any specific UUID for andorid devices??

Answer (score 0):

think of the UUID as one identifier for a particular kind of service your device is advertising or accepting. It could have many such identifiers for many different services it can offer or use. It's not an identifier for the actual device.

The UUID you are quoting is the same one I found here and use too. it seems to be the UUID for generic bluetooth SPP service. (but haven't found much actual proof like an official published document quot8ing this number, just posts on here with no refrence) This UUID will allow your android device to connect to things like bluetooth serial port adapters, or anything expecting a generic serial port device... so it's a good one to start with.

If you plan to create a special service that's not the same as bluetooth SPP or has a different reason to exist, like android chat does, then it's a good idea to create your own UUID. Of course all devices to connect your service will have to understand this same special number.